# Reflex: Sending multiple http requests for a dynamic list of entries on event

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, frp, ghcjs, reflex

Working with reflex-frp I have a list of entries which contain a text input. I also have a button that on click should trigger n http requests where n is the number of entries, and each request should contain the corresponding text. Therefore I have,

```
Event t [Text]
```

In order to send the requests I was trying to use

```
performRequestAsync :: MonadWidget t m => Event t XhrRequest -> m (Event t XhrResponse)
```

Therefore I need somehow a function that allows me to convert my event of list into a list of events:

```
Event t [Text] -> [Event t Text]
```

But I am not finding any way to do so. The most promising approach seems to involve the **fan** function and an **EventSelector** but I'm not being able to make much sense of it and there isn't much documentation online.

Is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried? It seems that `fan` or `fanMap` would work - what about these functions are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Using fan or fanMap you seem to have to know exact keys with which you'll be selecting events. Here the list is dynamic so you can't know the length - you can't pull it from the event.
So it looks like it all was designed to countermeasure such an idea.
Anyway creating multiple request for each element of the list is very unelegant and unefficient. If it's possible you should change your server API to allow batch requests.